# how to set image on background of button correctly

Tags: android, image

When I set an icon or an image as a background for a button, I always see something like this : 
[image]

as you can see, the images are smeared  (2 images on left side, and 2 images on right side)
Here is the code on how I added the icons(it's the defaults icon from android.R.Drawable...)

```
btnDown.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float));
btnUp.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float));
delete.setBackgroundDrawable(myIcon);
btnOk.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save));
```

can someone tell me how to set icon/image on background correctly ? Without them being smeared . if the icon is 32x32, I want see it on button.

Comment: its better to use ImageButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your image is too small thats why its looking like smeared ...use nine patch scaled image [this will help you](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Android-9-Patch-Scaled-Png-Image-Guide/)

Comment: default's icon from android (android.r.drawable) not in 9patch ?

Comment: i think only 9patch can help me